# Setting max lines on a Compose TextField

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to set the max lines on a `TextField` in Jetpack Compose? I see that `CoreTextField` has a `maxLines` property, but not `TextField`.

Comment: [It was recently merged.](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1482765)

Comment: Very recently. Good to know. thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Since [Compose 1.0.0-alpha07](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.0.0-alpha07), you can use [`maxLines`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#textfield) and [`overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis`] for adding ... at the end of lines ([for more info](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/configure-layout)):

```
TextField(
    value = "Hello World",
    onValueChange = {  },
    maxLines = 5,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
)
```